# Side by side divs in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, html, height

I have following html codes

```
<div align="center" style="width:1000px;border:1px solid green;">
        <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left; width:200px;  ">
        ssssssssssss </div>    
        <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left; width:200px;  ">
        ssssssssssss </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;  overflow: hidden;" id="endText">       
        xxx<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>x</p>           
    </div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

It works very fine in FF,Opera,Safari,Chrome, But in IE it shows wrong things. IE request predefined height for endText div for example

```
<div style="border:1px solid black;  overflow: hidden;height:117px; " id="endText">
```

What is the problem? Which addional CSS code may keep its visual properties in IE as like as other browsers?

Comment: Internet Explorer version 9 (IE9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in correct way. Please add any tag after your code and make #endText height as 100%.
It would be works as other browsers.

```
<div align="center" style="width:1000px;border:1px solid green;">
    <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left; width:200px; ">
        ssssssssssss </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left; width:200px; ">
        ssssssssssss </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black; height:100%" id="endText">
        xxx<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>x</p>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div> <hr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try floating #endText right and specifying a width? below i have used 594px as the borders are adding width.

```
<div align="center" style="width:1000px;border:1px solid green;">
    <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left; width:200px;">
        ssssssssssss
    </div>    
    <div style="border:1px solid red;float:left; width:200px;">
        ssssssssssss
    </div>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;  overflow: hidden; float: right; width: 594px" id="endText">       
    xxx<p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>x</p>           
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need it without specified width. Because I want #endText div cover remained area so first and second divs may change freely.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use positioning in CSS check out w3schools for how to make divs overlap, fixed etc

Comment: I looked there, but I couldn't find any things in this regard.